# separate output with comma in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just need to separate my out with a comma so it will print like this 1,2,fizz ect

```
for x in range (1, 21):
    if x%15==0:
        print("fizzbuzz",end=" ")
    elif x%5==0:
        print (("buzz"),end=" ") 
    elif x%3==0:
        print (("fizz"),end=" ")
    else:
        print (x,end=" ")
```

I can add a comma where " " is but my list will print with a comma at the end like 1,2,fizz,4,buzz,fizz,7,8,fizz,buzz,11,fizz,13,14,fizzbuzz,16,17,fizz,19,buzz,

I've gone over my notes and went on python tutorials but I am not sure how to get rid of the last comma or use a more effective method rather than just add that comma in instead of space.

I asked this before but I was confused by the wording so my question came out real confusing. I understand that this may be simple but this is my first time programming so I am a noob. My lecturer hasn't explained to me how I can do this. I could really use some help/ pointers. Thanks.

Comment: `for x in range(21): print(x%3//2*'Fizz'+x%5//4*'Buzz' or x+1)`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of printing them immediately, put everything is a list of strings. Then join the list with commas and print resulting string.

Comment: +1. Also, the functionality like in the question often becomes a function body. When writing functions, it is almost always better not to use `print()` inside. In theory, a function with `print` like calls is named as a *function with side effects*. It means it produces some output other than returning a value. In practice, functions with side effects are less universal. *Although practicality beats purity.*

Answer (score 4):

This could be a good example for learning generators. A generator looks like a normal function that uses `yield` instead of `return`. The difference is that when generator function is used, it behaves as an iterable object that produces a sequence of values. Try the following:

```
#!python3

def gen():
    for x in range (1, 21):
        if x % 15 == 0:
            yield "fizzbuzz"
        elif x % 5 == 0:
            yield "buzz"
        elif x % 3 == 0:
            yield "fizz"
        else:
            yield str(x)


# Now the examples of using the generator.
for v in gen():
    print(v)

# Another example.
lst = list(gen())   # the list() iterates through the values and builds the list object
print(lst)

# And printing the join of the iterated elements.
print(','.join(gen()))  # the join iterates through the values and joins them by ','

# The above ','.join(gen()) produces a single string that is printed.
# The alternative approach is to use the fact the print function can accept more
# printed arguments, and it is possible to set a different separator than a space.
# The * in front of gen() means that the gen() will be evaluated as iterable.
# Simply said, print can see it as if all the values were explicitly writen as 
# the print arguments.
print(*gen(), sep=',')
```

See the doc for the `print` function arguments at http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print, and `*expression` call argument at http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls.

Another advantage of the last `print` approach is that the arguments need not to be of the string type. The reason why the `gen()` definition explicitly used `str(x)` instead of plain `x` was because `.join()` requires that all joined values have to be of the string type. The `print` converts all the pased arguments to strings internally. If the `gen()` used plain `yield x`, and you insisted to use the join, the `join` could use a *generator expression* to convert the arguments to strings on the fly:

```
','.join(str(x) for x in gen()))
```

It displays on my console:

```
c:\tmp\___python\JessicaSmith\so18500305>py a.py
1
2
fizz
4
buzz
fizz
7
8
fizz
buzz
11
fizz
13
14
fizzbuzz
16
17
fizz
19
buzz
['1', '2', 'fizz', '4', 'buzz', 'fizz', '7', '8', 'fizz', 'buzz', '11', 'fizz',
'13', '14', 'fizzbuzz', '16', '17', 'fizz', '19', 'buzz']
1,2,fizz,4,buzz,fizz,7,8,fizz,buzz,11,fizz,13,14,fizzbuzz,16,17,fizz,19,buzz
1,2,fizz,4,buzz,fizz,7,8,fizz,buzz,11,fizz,13,14,fizzbuzz,16,17,fizz,19,buzz
```

Comment: +1 for converting into a generator... but instead of using `','.join` make use of `print` and do `print(*gen(), sep=',')` instead

Comment: It also means your generator needn't bother having to `yield str(x)` and just yield the number as it stands...