# FizzBuzz with commas instead of newlines

Tags: python-3.x, fizzbuzz

```
def fizz_buzz(i):
 if i % 15 == 0:
    return ("FizzBuzz")
 elif i % 5 == 0:
    return ("Buzz")
 elif i % 3 == 0:
    return ("Fizz")
 else:
    return (i)
for i in range(1, 21):
 print(fizz_buzz(i))
```

Where and how would do a new line command here with commas?

Trying to get an output like this: 1,2,Fizz,4,Buzz,Fizz,7,8,Fizz,Buzz,11,Fizz,13,14,FizzBuzz,16,17,Fizz,19, Buzz
but sideways and with commas.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish, can you give an example?

Comment: 1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
16
17
Fizz
19
Buzz
but sideways

Comment: That's still unclear, please edit your question to include an __exact__ example of what the output should be of `fizz_buzz(20)`.

Comment: sorry im new to this i just want to get this done

Comment: @Gilgamesh Specially for you: http://i.imgur.com/sgOJhRz.png

Answer (score 0):

Pass `end=','` to `print()`

```
def fizz_buzz(i):
 if i % 15 == 0:
    return ("FizzBuzz")
 elif i % 5 == 0:
    return ("Buzz")
 elif i % 3 == 0:
    return ("Fizz")
 else:
    return (i)
for i in range(1, 21):
 print(fizz_buzz(i), end=',')

# prints
1,2,Fizz,4,Buzz,Fizz,7,8,Fizz,Buzz,11,Fizz,13,14,FizzBuzz,16,17,Fizz,19,Buzz,
```

If you do not want the trailing comma, end the range at 20 and follow with `print(fizz_buzz(20))`

Answer (score 0):

Consider making a list & joining the elements with a comma.  There are some great examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500305/separate-output-with-comma-in-python-3?rq=1).

For example:

```
def fizz_buzz(i):
    # your code

my_list = []
for i in range(1,21):
    my_list.append( str(fizz_buzz(i)) )
print ",".join(my_list)
```

There are more elegant ways of doing this -- using generators &c, as in the linked answer --, but this simple code will do what you want.  Note that the `join()` method accepts string only, hence the `str()` in the `list.append()`; alternatively you could ensure that your `fizz_buzz` function returns strings regardless.